# I'm trying to create text that will wrap from edge to edge when paper is folded

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, text-wrap

**Background**

I want to preface this with saying that that all my knowledge of graphic design is in photoshop and illustrator and has all been self taught, I am by no means a professional graphic designer, I help people and do not get paid for any of my work. That said, Im trying to create a self standing flyer for tabletops for a non-profit veterans org, because they don’t have table tents.

**Setup**

I went with a landscape design of standard 11" x 8.5" so the ends can be taped together, creating a cylindrical stand-up flyer.  I set guidelines at 2.75 and 8.25 to create both sides.

**Question**

After designing the middle,  I'm having a problem finding information on **how to wrap text from the right side to the left side seamlessly while allowing for the seam itself**.

[image: Drawn Description]

Comment: Sorry but you really should reveal as a drawing the wanted final geometric form, the wanted continuously readable seams and some explanation why you do not print it as one piece, Are you maybe forced to use a low cost office printer with too small paper size? Are both sides printed and do you expect match between the sides? Self-standing is far too wide concept. Is it a single fold, two fold, is the folding horizontal, is it a  pyramide, a cylinder or what?

Comment: Hi and welcome to GDSE! I'm also looking forward to more information, but if I understand you correctly I believe the solution *is* "the long route" of adding the text twice. Not with "trial and error", but precise placement. Probably easiest and best to do in Illustrator. (Btw: Your dimensions are given in inches and they don't match the A4 format which would be about 11.69" x 8.27"?)

Answer (score 1):

I am writing these instructions for Adobe Illustrator but the concept applies to any program.

1. Get the distance the width of your text/text box. I created text that is 7" W. Make sure the text is centered align.
2. Create a box that is half the width of your text box.
3. Use the align panel to align your box to the right of the artboard.
4. Select both the text and the box and make sure the "Align to" is "Align to Key Object", make sure the key object is the box. Then choose the "Left Align" option in the Align Panel.
5. Copy the text and paste in place
6. Select the box, make the "Align to" to "Artboard" and choose "Left Align"
7. Copy step 4 but at the end make the text "Right Align"

[image: Screencast Demo]